# Функция оптимизации вектора с треугольниками

Tags: c++

У меня есть вектор с треугольниками. И в треугольниках совпадают вершины в некоторых. Мне нужно создать два вектора

```
using VertexBuffer = std::vector<Vector>;
using IndexBuffer = std::vector<VertexIndex>;
```

и в вектор VertexBuffer записывать вершины чтобы они не повторялись
А потом уже в IndexBuffer записать индексы с VertexBuffer . 
Я начал делать, и запутался, и не могу сделать задание. что б не делал все не то. Нужна ваша помощь. 
Пример:

```
 //1
v1=(0, 0, 0)
v2=(0, 1, 2)
v3=(0, 3, 3)

//2
v4=(0, 0, 0)
v5=(4, 5, 6)
v6=(0, 3, 3)

//3
v7=(4, 5, 6)
v8=(0, 0, 0)
v9=(0, 3, 3)

VertexBuffer
0.(0, 0, 0)
1.(0, 1, 2)
2.(0, 3, 3)
3.(4, 5, 6)

IndexBuffer
0, 1, 2
0, 3, 2
3, 0, 2
```

Код:

```
  std::pair<VertexBuffer, IndexBuffer> Optimize(const std::vector<Triangle>& triangles)
  {
      Triangle triangle;
      VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
      IndexBuffer indexBuffer;
      for (int index = 0; index < triangles.size(); ++index)
      {
         triangle = triangles[index];
         if (triangle != triangles[index])
             vertexBuffer[index] = triangles[index];

         for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
         {
            indexBuffer[i] = vertexBuffer[index];
         }
      }

      return std::pair<VertexBuffer, IndexBuffer>();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял задачу - взять map, в который заносить пары: `(ключ - координаты; значение - целочисленный индекс)`. Если координаты уже есть в map, то используем полученный из map индекс, иначе увеличиваем счетчик уникальных точек и используем его как значение новой пары и как индекс

```
точка  коорд  индекс
v1 = (0, 0, 0); 0
v2 = (0, 1, 2); 1
v3 = (0, 3, 3); 2
v4 = (0, 0, 0); 0
v5 = (4, 5, 6); 3
v6 = (0, 3, 3); 2
```

Если map нельзя, то принцип похож, только поиск будет происходить дольше, и индекс вместе с точкой хранить не надо:

```
для каждой точки:
   iter = std:find  в текущем vertexBuffer
   indexbuffer[] = iter - begin
   если iter = end //новая точка
         push точку в vertexBuffer
```

Comment: мне нужно именно через вектор  делать. в  задании вказано через вектор